# Insert data into firebase using hashmap

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have an image Uri saved into an Array. Now, I am trying to save those Uri into database. With the code below, it create each time a new ID. But, I wanted it to be all saved under one ID.

```
ArrayList<String> imageDUrlString = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < arrayuri.size(); i++) {
    imageDUrlString.add(arrayuri.get(i).toString());
}

Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("imageDownloadUrl", imageDUrlString);
DatabaseReference dbRefLicenseDoc = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

dbRefLicenseDoc.child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid()).child(postId)
        .updateChildren(map);
```

The code above produces this:

```
---User ID
   ---Random ID
      ----imageDownloadUrl
          ---- 0:"[https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/ image1
     ---Random ID
          ----imageDownloadUrl
          ---- 0:"[https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/ image2
   ---Random ID
      ----imageDownloadUrl
          ---- 0:"[https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/ image3
```

Is there a way to make it all Uri under a fixed ID that is under a user ID like this?

```
---User ID
   ----imageDownloadUrl
       ---- 0:"[https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/ image1
       ---- 1:"[https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/ image2
       ---- 3 :"[https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/ image3
```

I appreciate any suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
HashMap<String,String> imageDUrlString = new HashMap<>();
  DatabaseReference dbRefLicenseDoc = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

            dbRefLicenseDoc.child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid()).child("imageDownloadUrl");
            for (int i = 0; i < arrayuri.size(); i++) {
                imageDUrlString.put( dbRefLicenseDoc.push().getKey(),arrayuri.get(i).toString());
            }

                    dbRefLicenseDoc.updateChildren(map);
```

Hope it helps

Comment: In Logcat  Log.d(TAG, "imageDUrlString" + imageDUrlString); I see all the images download uri, it only saves the last one into database.

Comment: because it overwrite the values to new values if the keys is same ,
`push().getKey()` generate new unique key evey time